# MISRA.CAST.INT klocwork issue

Tags: c, misra, klocwork

We are fixing klocwork related issue getting MISRA.CAST.INT (The value of a complex expression of integer type shall only be cast to a type of the same signedness that is no wider than the underlying type of the expression.
)

```
uint32_t*               cptr;
uint32_t*               dptr;
uint16_t                blen;
dptr = PKA_ALIGN(cptr + blen + 1U);//getting error here
#define PKA_ALIGN(addr) (uint32_t *)(((uintptr_t)(addr) + (uint32_t)(8U - 1U)) & ~(uint32_t)(8U - 1U))
```

WHY is klocwork throwing error?

Comment: Which MISRA? I don't think the term "complex expression" exists in current MISRA C, it speaks of composite expressions. Are you using MISRA C:2004 or MISRA C++:2008? Please clarify or it's hard to answer the question.

Comment: I added the C tag for now, for code formatting purposes. If this is actually C++ please edit the tag.

Comment: Given that you are adding a `uint16_t` integer and multiple *plain unsigned integer* to a `uint32t *` pointer, never mind the cast to `uintptr_t`, I'm surprised you aren't getting other violations too (irrespective of the MISRA edition)

Comment: The specific MISRA edition and Rule would also be helpful for other users experiencing this issue.  Also, the define for PKA_ALIGN should be before it is used.